# How to compare two Web Services?

Tags: web-services

I am consuming a web service into my application. Now I have been informed that there will few changes in the web services but all methods(i.e. output from web service) exposed form the web service will not change.

I have got the WSDL link for both old and new webservices. Now, I want to compare the old and new webservice so that I can be sure that we are not missing any data.
Could anyone help me on the same i.e how to compare the two WSDLs?

Comment: What happens if you just compare the two documents with a text compare tool?

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL documents should have a "types" element with nested XMLSchema (e.g. `<xsd:schema>`) elements which may include import statements or inline XML schema definitions.

Compare the structure of the elements which are used as part of any "message" to see if there are any changes to their XML structure.

Comment: I am sorry but didn't get you, Could you please elaborate it a bit.